# What is the use of OP and CA operator in PDF creation and on which factor transparency is determined?

Tags: pdf, pdf-viewer

What is the use of the `OP` operator in PDF creation and with which factor is transparency determined?

```
q
0 g
0 G
1 w 10 M 
/GS4 gs
/Fm3 Do
Q
```

PDF source for `/Fm3`:

```
q
65.136 431.142 491.727 -307.179 re
W n
q
/GS0 gs
493.7399902 0 0 308.3157654 64.0563507 123.963913 cm
/Im0 Do
Q
Q
0 0 0 0 k
/GS1 gs
63.416 432.9 495 -310.32 re
f
```

Value of CA is 1, OPM is 1, OP is false in GS1 Extended graphic state.

Will the rectangle under the GS1 be fully transparent or fill transparent?

Answer (score 1):

> Value of CA is 1, OPM is 1, OP is false in GS1 Extended graphic state.

According to the [PDF specification](https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/pdfstandards/PDF32000_2008.pdf):

> **OP** boolean *(Optional)* A flag specifying whether to apply overprint. In PDF 1.2 and earlier, there is a single overprint parameter that applies to all painting operations. Beginning with PDF 1.3, there shall be two separate overprint parameters: one for stroking and one for all other painting operations. Specifying an **OP** entry shall set both parameters unless there is also an **op** entry in the same graphics state parameter dictionary, in which case the **OP** entry shall set only the overprint parameter for stroking.
>
> **OPM** integer *(Optional; PDF 1.3)* The overprint mode.
>
> **CA** number *(Optional; PDF 1.4)* The current stroking alpha constant, specifying the constant shape or constant opacity value that shall be used for stroking operations in the transparent imaging model.
>
> *(Table 58 – Entries in a Graphics State Parameter Dictionary)*
>
> If the overprint parameter is **false** (the default value), painting a colour in any colour space shall cause the corresponding areas of unspecified colorants to be erased (painted with a tint value of 0.0). The effect is that the colour at any position on the page is whatever was painted there last, which is consistent with the normal painting behaviour of the opaque imaging model.
>
> An additional graphics state parameter, the overprint mode (PDF 1.3), shall affect the interpretation of a tint value of 0.0 for a colour component in a **DeviceCMYK** colour space when overprinting is enabled. This parameter is controlled by the **OPM** entry in a graphics state parameter dictionary; it shall have an effect only when the overprint parameter is **true**, as described above.
>
> *(section 8.6.7 Overprint Control)*

Thus, `/GS1 gs` switches off overprinting and selects opaque stroking.

The opacity of filling is not changed in any way by that operation.

So to determine

> whether the rectangle under the GS1 will be fully transparent or fill transparent

one has to know more about the graphics state before, especially

- did `/GS4 gs` (or any even earlier graphics state change) alter the fill opacity and
- does **Fm3** define (or is it part of) a transparency group with properties relevant here.

Furthermore which is the current blend mode? Some blend modes can have effects reminding of opacity.